# Stabilizability as a weaker notion

Tags: control, linear

I'm having trouble understanding why stabilizability is weaker than controllability and whereas the latter implies the former, the converse isn't true. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: If you can control something, you can stabilize it _by_ controlling it, by controlling it to go to a stable state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical way to put it:

1. A system is stabilizable when closed-loop poles can be placed in a region contained within the left-half of the s-plane.
2. A system is controllable when closed-loop poles can be placed in any desired position of the s-plane.
3. The left-half of the s-plane is a subset of the s-plane.

Therefore, when a system is controllable, it is stabilizable. You can place the closed-loop poles anywhere, *including* a region in the left-half of the s-plane.

When a system is stabilizable, controllability **isn't** implied. You can place the closed-loop poles in a region contained within the left-half of the s-plane, but not necessarily *anywhere* in the s-plane.

Comment: Thanks for this. I also came across an alternate argument: If a system is stabilizable, then $$ \exists u(t)  :  \lim_{t \to \infty} x(t) = 0$$ but for controllability, this must be accomplished in finite time. Hence, it's stronger. Does this support your explanation?

Comment: This equation actually defines asymptotic stability. A system can be controllable and be asymptotic stable in the closed-loop. I do not agree with this statement.